# 획순에 맞게 쓰기 - what does 에 mean and function as?

Tags: grammar

What does 에 mean or function as in the sentence below? 
Why use 에 and not 은 or 을?

> "획순에 맞게 쓰기"

Comment: 은 is usually used for subject, and 을 is usually used for object. 에 usually means 'to'.

Comment: Could you provide more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`획순에 맞게 쓰기` translates to `Writing Correctly to the order of strokes` where *획순* is the *the order of strokes*.

**1. What does 에 mean or function as in the sentence below?**

`에` functions loosely as  `to` here.

**2. Why use `에` and not `은` or `을`?**

- `획순을 맞게 쓰기` translates to `Writing the order of strokes correctly`,
  and it makes some sense.
- `획순은 맞게 쓰기` translates (forcefully) to `The order of strokes should
  write correctly`, and it really doesn't make sense unless it's
  presented in a specific context.